# Is there a way to click an element before the page loading completes

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way in `selenium 2` to click on any element before the page loading action is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

> Dependent on several factors, including the OS/Browser combination, WebDriver may or may not wait for the page to load. ([Source](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#fetching-a-page))

You may be able to click on an element before the page loads *sometimes*, but it cannot be guaranteed, and I'm pretty sure wanting to do so goes against most of the principles of using WebDriver in the first place. What are you trying to achieve?